# I don't understand why am i getting this error when running a container of my docker image

Tags: node.js, docker

i am trying to create an image for my nodejs app but encountered an error which i am having trouble understanding

sorry for the newbie question but i'm not quite familiar docker yet. In fact, i'm still learning

so here is my Dockerfile

```
# Install dependencies 
FROM node:14-alpine AS deps
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile


# Create a build from the source code
FROM node:14-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
COPY --from=deps /usr/app/node_modules ./node_modules
RUN cd ./common && yarn link
RUN yarn link common
RUN yarn run build && yarn install --production --ignore-scripts --prefer-offline


# Set-up production image
FROM node:14-alpine AS runner
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=builder /app/dist ./dist
COPY --from=builder /app/common ./common
COPY --from=builder /app/ormconfig.js ./ormconfig.js
COPY --from=builder /app/package.json ./package.json
COPY --from=builder /app/fixtures ./fixtures

ENV PORT=$PORT \
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET=$ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET \
ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFE=$ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFE \
BCRYPT_SALT_ROUND=$BCRYPT_SALT_ROUND \
NODE_ENV="production" \
ORIGIN_URL=$ORIGIN_URL \
DB_USERNAME=$DB_USERNAME \
DB_PASSWORD=$DB_PASSWORD \
DB_NAME=$DB_NAME \
DB_HOST=$DB_HOST \
DB_PORT=$DB_PORT

EXPOSE 3002

RUN ls -la

CMD ["node", "--input-type=module", "dist/index.js"]
```

this is the outpout of the `ls -la` command in the last stage of the build

```
drwxr-xr-x    6 root     root             8 Jun 16 21:40 .
drwxr-xr-x   20 root     root            21 Jun 16 21:40 ..
drwxr-xr-x    5 root     root            12 Jun 16 21:40 common
drwxr-xr-x    4 root     root             5 Jun 16 21:40 dist
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root             5 Jun 16 21:40 fixtures
drwxr-xr-x  353 root     root           355 Jun 16 21:40 node_modules
-rw-rw-r--    1 root     root           485 May  5 13:39 ormconfig.js
-rw-rw-r--    1 root     root          1925 Jun  7 12:14 package.json
```

and the error i ran into when i launch a container with this previously created image

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:905
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/app/dist/index.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

i dont really understand why it fails to access `/app/dist/index.js`. in my CMD instruction, i clearly tell him to launch the node process from dist/index.js not app/dist/index.js ..

it seems trivial, but i'm sure there is something i misunderstood ..

thanks

Comment: It is trying to run the expected file. Are you sure there is an `index.js` in `dist` ?

Comment: Can you change `RUN ls -la` to `RUN ls -la /app/dist` to verify that the file is there?

Comment: yup, the structure of the dist file was different that's why he could not found the index.js file .. thanks